# Is there a way to set my own Office 2013 background?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2013

In Office 2013, in most of the applications, there is a general options page.  On this page, there is a place to select an Office Theme and the Office background.

The Office Background give a list of about 15 options, and the "Background is actually a grey-scale image that appears on the right-hand side of all office applications.

Is there a way to make and select my own backgrounds by either official or unofficial means?

**EDIT**

See image below for what I'd like to change to an image I've created.

[image]

Comment: @Private I'm sure there isn't a way to do this through the menu structure, but if there is some form of bitmapped file stored somewhere within Office/Windows, I'm not afraid to modify one for my own purpose.  I can't find where anyone has tried to do this and some times you can be pleasantly surprised how easy these minor adjustments can be, so long as you know where to look.